# What does "pogo bleed" entail?

Tags: falcon-9, falcon-heavy, liquid-fuel, merlin-1d, tanks

At around T-3:00 on every Falcon 9 countdown, we [hear](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6JAdKoQyN4&t=4s) the following:

> Stage 1 pogo bleed verification

I assume they are referring to [pogo oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_oscillation), but what exactly does "pogo bleed" mean and what does it entail?

Comment: Most boosters have a pogo prevention system consisting of accumulators in the LOX system to dampen out oscillations. No knowledge of Falcon details though.